# What if Publisher cannot produce data when Subscription.request is called?

Tags: java, rx-java, project-reactor, reactive-streams

As in the title: What if `Publisher` cannot produce data when `Subscription.request` is called? Should it wait to produce any data anyway (blocking)? Should I subscribe it again to retry?

Comment: then `Publisher` remembers the request and works to satisfy it. And when done, will call `subscribrer.onNext()`. Nobody is blocked. No need to retry subscription or request.

Comment: Ok. But what about several publishers merged into one? For example with `Flux.merge` from `Project Reactor`? If the first one cannot produce, can we withdraw the request and ask another publisher to publish?

Comment: Never used Flux.merge. Looked at the javadoc and saw it saying "into an interleaved merged sequence" which means, I believe, the publishers are requested sequentially, and if one is not ready to issue next value, the whole merged flow is suspended. But again, no one thread is blocked.

Comment: But the flow is suspended. I need it to try requesting new values if nothing arrives.

Comment: these are the programs, not humans. If it cannot sent data after the first request, it will not send after the second.

Comment: Yes It could. Let assume that `Publisher` is receiving data from queue. The queue could be empty and in that case we want to switch to another source and at the end back to the first one.

Comment: `Flux.merge` does not work this way. If you want to develop your own merger, go on. Do it from scratch.

Comment: So, there is no such merger in `Project Reactor` which can satisfy my requirements? What about `RxJava`?

Comment: I don't know. I am not a big specialist in these libraries.